# AngularJS - Delete check box is not working correctly and only deleting one at a time

Tags: angularjs, spring

I've written out a block of code that allows the user to check or uncheck entities that will be added or removed via web services. My add function seems to be working correctly and provides the ability to add multiple entities. However, my delete function isn't working the same. It doesn't delete each time, and can only delete one at a time. I'm struggling since the code is effectively the same as the add, so I don't know if the issue is AngularJS related or perhaps my web service isn't working correctly.

Edit: I've actually noticed that the for loop goes through it all but doesn't select the correct id, it always starts from the first one.

```
var toDeleteService = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.siteServices.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.siteServices[i].chosen != $scope.siteServices[i].origChosen) {
            if ($scope.siteServices[i].chosen == true) {
                toAddService.push(i);
            }
            else {
                toDeleteService.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    if (toDeleteService.length > 0) {
        var deleteRequest = {};
        deleteRequest.services = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < toDeleteService.length; i++) {
            var parentServiceName = $scope.siteServices[i].parentServiceName;
            var j = 0;
            for (; j < deleteRequest.services.length; j++) {
                if (deleteRequest.services[j].parentServiceName == parentServiceName) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (j == deleteRequest.services.length) {
                deleteRequest.services[j] = {};
                deleteRequest.services[j].parentServiceName = parentServiceName;
                deleteRequest.services[j].subservices = [];
            }
            var service = {};
            service.serviceId = $scope.siteServices[i].serviceId;

            deleteRequest.services[j].subservices.push(service);
        }

        var deleteUrl = "api/sites/" + $scope.targetEntity.siteId + "/services/" + service.serviceId;

        $http.delete(deleteUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
            });
    }
```

Comment: strange for you got there

Comment: `for (; j < deleteRequest.services.length; j++)`

Comment: you use i and j outside the loops

Comment: @madalinivascu Could you provide an answer to the question, not a comment by any chance, please?

Comment: An advice.Try adding some short comments to your code for clarity. Goes a long way when trying to debug things. I cannot figure out why you using so many checks and if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood it you are trying to remove siteServices based by numbers stored in `var toDeleteServices = []` so you need to access those numbers by its index. but in `service.serviceId = $scope.siteServices[i].serviceId;` you are using `i` instead.

`service.serviceId = $scope.siteServices[toDeleteServices[i]].serviceId;` as you need actual number of the service to delete.
If I understood your code correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.